# Connecting PostGIS raster data to GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgis-raster

The data I have used is DEM. It creates a table and has 2 columns in PostGIS.

Is it necessary to create a new table again and follow the configuration process as mentioned in the [Image Mosaic JDBC documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/jdbc/index.html#im-jdbc)?

The error -

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/01/20 19:28:24 | java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving
>   them: Failed to create reader from file:coverages/oek.pgraster.xml.xml
>   and hints null INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/01/20 19:28:24 |  at
>   org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:151)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/01/20 19:28:24 |     at
>   org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:59)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/01/20 19:28:24 |     at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.fullSize(GeoServerDataProvider.java:242)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/01/20 19:28:24 |     at
>   ......

I removed the rest of the redundant log entries.

Answer (score 7):

Setting up geoserver to use postgis raster is not an easy job. Also, you have to rethink the reason why you are using postgis raster to store your rasters. Postgis does *NOT* make access to your raster faster or easier (actually, it makes it slower). It would't help you much in the administration of files, since you have to script that anyway and geoserver doesn't allow for much administration of these rasters either. The only good reason I can imagine to use postgis raster would be because you are doing a lot of analysis in combination with vectors that are also in postgis and you want to serve the (raster) results of this analysis as soon as possible via geoserver.

With that out of the way:
Postgis raster cannot be directly opened from geoserver but requires the [image mosaic plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html)
After installing this plugin you can use this [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html) to apply a bunch of settings manually. But beware, you are entering rather uncharted area.

Comment: Is there any update for this answer? I saw a community extension called PGRaster (https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/pgraster/pgraster.html) but it is not available for download!