# Publishing raster data in OpenLayers applications

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

I need tips for publishing raster data in my OpenLayers application.I published shapefiles through my postgis db (PgAdmin) to geoserver, not sure how to do that for raster? I readed that is not cleaver idea [in this answer][1]https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181575/160696 
I have map of municipality tiff format (1,6 GB) and i want to import that map as Layer to include in LayerSwitsher window.So my question is how? I had already published my raster data in db (not on Geoserver), but now I'm thinking what to do? Maybe to try directly?

Comment: Interesting thing is when I connect QGIS with db and drag my raster into QGIS, it's incredibly slow and breaks constantly...so I ask myself would that happen through geoserver and on my OL app...